# One nasty masonry IE bug

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I got this website. Using masonry. As you can see at
www.thecmyk.se/clients/1/

the divs/blocks works fine with Google chrome, Firefox etc. But when I'm using IE
the upper right div called "The 14 day challenge" does not lay down as the other boxes. (it kind of floats up to the "Who do you think you are" div)

Ive tried for a couple of hours now but I cant make it look like the other divs. (Padding top).

Any 1 who can help me out a bit here?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by external font. If you change font in box above it to 'sans-serif' everything will look correctly. As a hint, I can see error in console:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
AilHuqCBdowNtWlpkIeGEg.eot
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Thank you thank you and once again thank you!